# Python iterforest has no attribute IterImput

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

Executing the following code:

```
from ycimpute.imputer import iterforest 
dff = iterforest.IterImput().complete(n_df)
```

I am having this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'ycimpute.imputer.iterforest' has no attribute 'IterImput'
```

I tried to search but I think there is not a lot of information about this specific thing on internet.

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively use the following 2 ways to get results with the same method (Random forest missing imputation).

way 1: with missingpy

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).